# s3sh commandline ubuntu still exists(EC2,s3 amazon)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, ubuntu, upload, amazon-s3

Am using Ruby on Rails and aws/s3 gem to upload files. Somewhere I read there is a commandline tool "s3sh" to test the upload. But I can't find it.Is that still exits? Anybody knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `s3sh` command comes with the `aws/s3` gem so it should be in your path. Usually it's not too hard to track down if it has gone missing.

Have a look at the output of `gem contents aws-s3` and see where the `s3sh` command is located. That might be in a directory you need to add to your default `PATH`.

That's as easy as putting something like this in your `.bashrc` if using bash. Here's an example based on OS X using MacPorts and RVM:

```
PATH="/opt/local/rvm/rubies/default/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/bin:$PATH"
```

Where it shows up can be somewhat of a mystery, so it's good to pay attention to the result of the `gem contents` listing.